# How to get child relation from collection

Tags: laravel, relationship

When i listing my model laravel return me all i wont. Even relation that has relation

```
$data = City::where('id',example_id)
    ->with('x.xy')
    ->with('c')
    ->with('v')
    ->with('b')
    ->first();
```

`$data` have got all i want, even "x" relation which has got "xy" relation.

I receive City with 4 relations(x(with xy),c,v,b). But when i try assign "x" with "xy" like that :
`$something = $data->x()->get()`. The `$something` variable does not contain "xy" relation. Variable only contain "x" without "xy" relation.

Dump from `$something` return "x" with empty relation ( `relation:[]` ).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = City::where('id',example_id)->first();
$something = $data->x()->with('xy')->get()
```

or

```
$data = City::where('id',example_id)
    ->with('x.xy')
    ->first();

$something = $data->x;
```